# how can i show my left navigation menu above all of the activity component?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

what i have is a left navigation side bar which i made using the navigation drawer .. it works just fine but also in the same layout for the activity i have a three buttons .. and each time the menu appears it appears under the three buttons which is so weird .. i want this menu to appear above everything else in the activity .. here is my xml code :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@string/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" 
   >
   <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <!-- Listview to display slider menu -->
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#ffffff"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"        
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
        android:background="#703534"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/catalogue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/our_products" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="170sp"
        android:layout_height="60sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:background="@drawable/contact_us" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

can anyone help me??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The order of how you define things in the xml decide how they appear on the screen, also determines which view appears above or below which other view. For a Nav Drawer, The layout should be something like this :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:font="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.teewe.client"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >


    <!-- This LinearLayout is the layout for your activity. Replace with FrameLayout -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_from_screen_edges" >

    </LinearLayout>

    <!--The last view that you include, shows up in your drawer. In this case, everything inside this RelativeLayout shows up in the drawer. --> 

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerRelativeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/nowPlayingLayout"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@color/light_gray"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: and where is the frame layout went?

Comment: Check Edits. I haven't edited your layout, just explained how things work. You can modify as required.

Comment: can you explain more please.. because i have fragment and relative layout and a drawer in the same xml file .. ??

Comment: Your buttons always come above your drawer because you have placed them after the layout for your drawer. The order in which you define things, the views appear in the very same order.

Comment: but i have tried to put them before .. my code crash !!

Comment: and what does the logcat say ?